# How to superimpose/overlay QLabels which contain tranpartent PNG images?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, layout

I'm trying to implement a progress bar of some sort, with a grid in front of it.
I have a PNG with transparent "holes" in it, to be used as a mask in front of the progress bar.

I tried creating a `QStackedLayout`, with two labels in it: one will be filled with a solid color, and the other one will contain the PNG for the overlay.

I thought `QStackedLayout::StackAll` would allow all widgets in the layout to be visible.

```
QStackedLayout *stackedLayout = new QStackedLayout(ui->widget_progressbar);
stackedLayout->setStackingMode(QStackedLayout::StackAll);

label_fill = new QLabel();
label_fill->setFixedSize(100, 100); // just for testing
label_fill->setStyleSheet("background-color: #669966");
stackedLayout->addWidget(label_fill);

label_foreground = new QLabel();
label_foreground->setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/mask.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;");
stackedLayout->addWidget(label_foreground);
```

With the above code, the green rectangle is in the foreground, covering the mask. If I re-order their addition to the layout, or if I use `stackedLayout->setCurrentWidget(label_foreground);` or `label_foreground->raise();`, then the `label_fill` is not visible at all. The transparent holes in the PNG show the background color of the widget the layout is in. This I confirmed with changing the color of the parent widget, and I could see the changed color in the transparent holes.

I use the `border-image` in the stylesheet so that the image is automatically scaled. However, using the `background-image` style or just simply `label_foreground()->setPixmap(...)` instead, it still has the same transparency issues.

What is the "official" way of doing this?

Of course, if I really have to, I can do it with editing QPixmaps, but then I will have to take care of resize events. Is there a way of solving this with layouts, without having to implement my own layout manager?

I think I'll resort to using a `QGraphicsScene`, but I'm still curious whether there is a solution with basic layouts.

Comment: Look at QWidget::autoFillBackground documentation. There's a warning there that this property is disabled when you use a style sheet with a border-image, which you have. I'm not sure exactly what the effect of that is, but instead of using style sheets, you might use setPixmap instead.

Comment: @goug : Unfortunately, the same happens with setPixmap, as already mentioned in the question.

Comment: I've re-read the question, and you didn't actually say that you tried this with setPixmap rather than stylesheets. Perhaps you meant to imply that, but it's certainly not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my `label_foreground` inherited the style sheet of its parent (`ui->widget_progressbar`), so it had a solid background color. In the transparent holes of the PNG image, it was not the parent I saw, but the background color of the label itself.

Adding a transparent background to the label solved the problem: it now correctly shows other widgets below it through the transparent parts of the image:

```
label_foreground->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); border-image: url(:/img/mask.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;");
```